# Set time out for mysql service it couldn't started/stopped after sometime using java program in windows

Tags: java, mysql, windows, eclipse, service

In windows,I am trying to write a java program to stop mysql service and update my.ini file, then start the mysql service. It can works successfully. I can check the status of mysql service, that is  started/stopped by using java code. If any unpredicted conditions occurs, the specified service couldn't started/stopped and also it can looping. Please check my code:

```
public void processStatusOfMySQLService() {

    String[] commandScript = { "cmd.exe", "/c", "sc", "query", "MySQL" };

    String STATE_PREFIX = "STATE              : ";



    Process process;

    try {

        process = new ProcessBuilder(commandScript).start();

        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String line;

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // check that the temp string contains the status prefix

            int indexStatus = line.indexOf(STATE_PREFIX);

            if (indexStatus >= 0) {

                // compare status number to one of the states

                String stateStr = line.substring(

                        indexStatus + STATE_PREFIX.length(),

                        indexStatus + STATE_PREFIX.length() + 1);

                int state = Integer.parseInt(stateStr);

                switch (state) {

                case (1): 

                    // service stopped

                    break;

                case (4):

                    // service started

                    break;

                case (2):

                case (3):

                    // service pending

                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(1000);

                        processStatusOfMySQLService();

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

                }

            }



        }

        br.close();

        isr.close();

        is.close();

        process.destroy();



    }
```

I need to break from the loop after a specific time if the service can't started/stopped. How to set an appropriate time out value???

Comment: From my experience, dealing with Process is not very straight forwards. I recommend you look at apache common exec https://commons.apache.org/exec/